# ClearTeam Explorer contacting expired license host

Tags: clearcase

I can't get ClearTeam Explorer to register a new license server. It keeps referring to the old one.

The error I get back when I try to connect is that  it can't connect to LICENSE_HOST_X.

I've changed the setting in 'Home Base's control panel to point to the new LICENSE_HOST_Y, which works for the clearlicense tool and clearcase doctor but not for the team explorer.

Answer (score 2):

The license settings are contained in the Windows Registry at HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Atria\ClearCase\CurrentVersion\Licensehost for Atria licenses.

For FlexNet licenses, the PortAtHost value at HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Rational Software\Licensing\8.0\ServerList comes into play as well.

The odds are VERY good that you're dealing with Windows registry virtualization. If you open the legacy "control panel" on Windows 10, run the "ClearCase" control panel as Administrator (or open "cc.cpl" from an elevated command prompt) and check the server information there. If you see different values for EXPLICITLY elevated and non-explicltly elevated control panel starts, you have entries in the "user specific" virtual registry store. Please note that this is a WINDOWS function, and not a ClearCase one.

Disabling the albd service on the license server is a very bad idea unless that is the only function the albd is providing. Disabling it on the client will essentially kill any local views AND the ability to map views to drives when the "credential manager" service that depends on this service fails to start.

Comment: Brilliant. Finally I know where the registry settings are. There was a bit of PEBCAC. I had changed the license host setting to a third variant. There doesn't appear to be any negative effects from stopping the service(client side). I am using web views.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore. I've experimented a bit more by restarting the albd service several times. There's some weird form of persistency going on. I suspect that the 'Use registry server on host:' setting has something to do with it. Anyways, thanks much.

Comment: @V.Bogd If you're using web views, you need to be looking at the WAN server's license configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still puzzled though. It almost certainly appeared that there's a _local_ component to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check if any of elements mentioned in "[How to change the hostname in the IBM Rational ClearCase environment](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/change-hostname-ibm-rational-clearcase/index.html)" might have an influence in your case.

> IBM Rational ClearCase supports two types of licenses, the Rational Common Licensing (FlexLM) and the Classic Atria licensing.
>
> Update these files with the new host name:
>
> - Rational common licensing (FlexLM):
>
> ```
> /var/adm/rational/clearcase/config/flexlm_host
> ```
>
> - Rational ClearCase Classic/Atria licensing:
>
> ```
> /var/adm/rational/clearcase/config/license_host
> ```

So it can help to know if the new license server is of a different nature than the old one.

At the client level:

> ### UNIX/Linux clients:
>
> Update the new registry server's host name in the file `/var/adm/rational/clearcase/config/rgy_svr.conf`
>
> Update the License Server using the instructions in the server configuration guidelines.
>
> ### Windows clients:
>
> Update the new registry and license server hostname information using the IBM Rational ClearCase control panel located under the Windows control panel.

If nothing work, I would, if my client is on Windows, search for the old license server name in the Windows Registry, and replace or even delete those entries.

---

On Windows, the [OP V.Bogd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14137742/v-bogd) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63774959/clearteam-explorer-contacting-expired-license-host/63783606?noredirect=1#comment112801782_63783606):

> The problem went away after I disabled an "**Atria Location Broker**" service.

That was the service needed, as [seen in this thread](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/windows-fatal-exception-error-no-license-available-clearcase-license-manager), for the old license manager:

```
No license available from ClearCase license manager; 
Use clearlicense to display license usage
```

You can see more on [`albd_server.exe` here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/methods-changing-albd-password-albdserverexe).

Comment: Thanks Von. I am on Windows and I couldn't find a reference to either of the license hosts in the registry. Making me wonder where is the setting actually stored. Anyway, the problem went away after I disabled an "Artria Location Broker" service.

Comment: @V.Bogd Strange indeed. I have included your comment in the answer, with some additional links.